# Set connect from another class in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I don't get it.

loginview.h

```
#ifndef LOGINVIEW_H
#define LOGINVIEW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QPushButton>

class LoginView : public QWidget
{

public:
    QWidget *LoginViewSetup(QWidget * wdgMain);

public slots:
    virtual void LogInUser();
    virtual void CreateUser();

public:
    QPushButton *logInBtn;
    QPushButton *createBtn;

};

#endif // LOGINVIEW_H
```

loginview.cpp

```
#include "loginview.h"

QWidget *LoginView::LoginViewSetup(QWidget * wdgMain)
{    
    //some code
    return wdgCenter;
}

void LoginView::LogInUser()
{
    //some code
}

void LoginView::CreateUser()
{
    //some code
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDebug>

#include <loginview.h>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QWidget * wdgMain;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    wdgMain = new QWidget(this);

    LoginView LoginViewObj;
    QWidget *wdgCenter = LoginViewObj.LoginViewSetup(wdgMain);

    setCentralWidget( wdgMain );

    connect(LoginViewObj.createBtn, SIGNAL (released()), &LoginViewObj, SLOT (CreateUser()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Problem:

> QObject::connect: No such slot QWidget::CreateUser() in
>   ../proj/mainwindow.cpp:16

I tried to add `Q_OBJECT` to the loginview.h and then rebuild project with QMAKE. After that there is no warning about slot, but buttons still not active. Program don't jump to handle of the button in debug mode.

Please, help me to understand what's wrong? I have an object of another class LoginView and I pass this object as a reciever for a slot. Why it passes through my class and searches slot in QWidget?

Comment: You forgot to add `Q_OBJECT` to your header for `LoginView`. So no slot will be created.

Comment: @drescherjm, just updated. Doesn't help.

Comment: Did you run qmake.

Comment: @drescherjm, yes I ran qmake.

Comment: @drescherjm, not a duplicate, different problems

Comment: @drescherjm, YES. thank you very much.

Comment: I now think the problem is with `LoginViewObj.createBtn`. Sorry for so many guesses.. Does `LoginViewObj.createBtn` exist when the connect() is called?

Comment: Use the new style signal slot syntax (modeled on function pointers) to get compile-time checking for connections.